# Python Condition

Tags: python, selenium, loops, conditional-statements

I'm creating a conditional loop in python but it's not working. What do you think could be the reason or how else can it be done?
In this way, I am looking for the necessary information here.

```
   try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(
            lambda d: d.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='sc-bczRLJ iBneUr mde-consent-accept-btn']")).click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(
            lambda d: d.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[@class='phone-number-container']")).click()
        tel_number = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[@class='phone-number-container']").text
        print(tel_number)

    except:
        tel_number = ' '
```

> There is also a tel number filter like this

Comment: Where is the loop? (You only have an `if` statement). What error message are you seeing?

Comment: Maybe you are right. I don't get an error but it doesn't enter this part, it skips.I need a loop that satisfies the double condition, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You're probably looking for a Python `for` loop. And you'll want to loop over a list of items. Inside the loop, put in the `if` statement, and have it call `continue` if the correct conditions aren't satisfied, which will restart the loop with the next item in the list.

Comment: I have added the fields I want above.

Comment: There is also such a word field.